# How to Specify Correct Marshaling for DLL Import in C#

Tags: c, dll, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am using DLL Import to use some functionality in a C dll. The signature of the function is

```
int dllfunction(myfile **fptr, const char *filename, int *status);
```

What marshalling code goes into the line below so I can access the function?

```
[DllImport("name.dll")]
public static extern int dllfunction(??);
```

I have tried

```
[DllImport("name.dll")]
public static extern int dllfunction(
    IntPtr fptr,
    [In] ref char filename, 
    ref int status);
```

Looking at MSDN has not helped yet. If you are able to give a reply, would you mind giving a calling example as well (i.e. in case casts are required).

Thanks for Looking!

Buck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best guess with what little info was posted:

```
[DllImport("name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int dllfunction(
    out IntPtr fptr, 
    string filename, 
    ref int status
);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. What other information do you think would have potentially helped so I can consider next time? Thanks again.

Comment: Describe what the function does.  The out and ref in the declaration were guesses.

Comment: Got it - Thanks. I can be more specific, if needed, on a future post.